Create an SshSessionFactory for JGit with Apache Mina authenticated with a private key on a client perspective
I want to migrate this code under Jsch to Mina:
File privateKey = new File("/path/to/local/privateKeyFile");

Repository repository = new FileRepositoryBuilder()
    .setMustExist(true)
    .setGitDir(new File("/path/to/local/repo/.git"))
    .build();

Git git = new Git(repository);

PullCommand pullCmd = git.pull()
    .setTransportConfigCallback(transport ->
         SshTransport sshTransport = (SshTransport) transport;
         sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory(
                                         
             new JschConfigSessionFactory() {
                
                 @Override
                 protected void configure(OpenSshConfig.Host host, Session session) {
                     session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                 }

                 @Override
                 protected JSch createDefaultJSch(FS fs) throws JSchException {
                     JSch defaultJSch = new JSch();
                     defaultJSch.addIdentity(privateKey.getAbsolutePath());
                     return defaultJSch;
                 }
             };
                                            
    );
});

The issue being Azure end of SSH-RSA support for repos which leads us to update to RSA-SHA2-512 but it creates this error which seems because JSch doesn't support it as explained here in a similar case with GitHub.
I found the GitHub documentation of Mina for the client side but I don't understand how to create a sshdSessionFactory in my use case. What I tried:
File privateKey = new File("/path/to/local/privateKeyFile");

Repository repository = new FileRepositoryBuilder()
    .setMustExist(true)
    .setGitDir(new File("/path/to/local/repo/.git"))
    .build();

Git git = new Git(repository);

SshClient client = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient();
client.setKeyIdentityProvider(new FileKeyPairProvider(privateKey.toPath()));

client.start();

PullCommand pullCmd = git.pull()
    .setTransportConfigCallback(transport ->
         SshTransport sshTransport = (SshTransport) transport;
         sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory(new GitSshdSessionFactory(client));
    );
});

client.stop();

It seems I'm missing something. Do you have any idea how to do so?

Jsch fork, no code change needed
Using this GitHub fork instead of the official Jsch fixed it.
I changed in my maven pom.xml:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.jsch</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0.202012080955-r</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0.202012080955-r</version>
        </dependency>

to:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.jsch</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0.202012080955-r</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mwiede</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.18</version>
        </dependency>

I'll complete this answer when I manage to implement the Apache Mina version..
